# Bibliotecas C fora do padrão ANSI

Tags: c, biblioteca, ansi

Estou ciente de que um programa em C no padrão ANSI pode ser compilado tanto em Windows, tanto em Linux.

Mas quando se trata em usar *sockets*? Isso não faz parte do padrão ANSI C? Porque quando uso sockets no Windows, eu tenho que usar uma biblioteca chamada `"Winsock.h"`, no Linux, essa biblioteca não existe, e ele usa outra biblioteca chamada `"socket.h"`. Nesse caso, um programa no Windows que utiliza a biblioteca `"Winsock.h"`, dará erro quando compilado em um Linux, e vise-versa. Entretanto, Sockets não estão no padrão?

Outra coisa é a função `fork()`, essa função existe apenas no Linux para fazer threads, acredito. Logo essa função, sendo inexistente no Windows, está fora do padrão ANSI C?

Comment: Ora aqui está uma boa pergunta +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você acertou. As bibliotecas de *sockets* não fazem parte do ANSI. Este padrão define apenas sobre a linguagem e tudo o que é considerado a [biblioteca padrão da linguagem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) que possui apenas operações bem básicas, para fazer o mínimo necessário e que não costuma se envolver com o sistema operacional a não ser em coisas bem simples e padronizadas como acesso ao terminal e arquivos, por exemplo.

Mesmo esses acessos ao sistema operacional são feitos de forma limitada. Quando se deseja acesso mais sofisticado já precisa de bibliotecas fora do padrão que podem estar disponíveis ou não para vários compiladores, sistemas operacionais ou mesmo processadores.

O mesmo vale para funções que manipulam processos como o `fork()`.

Nestes casos costumam existir bibliotecas que abstraem o sistema operacional. Ou seja, elas internamente sabem como trabalhar com cada sistema operacional onde será usada mas externamente funciona da mesma maneira.

Exemplos:

- [GLib channels](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-IO-Channels.html)
- [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv)
- [Apache](http://apr.apache.org/)

Todas estas trabalham pelo menos com Windows sockets e POSIX sockets.

- [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/)
- [gLib threads](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html)
- [Open Threads](http://openthreads.sourceforge.net/)

Todos permitem trabalhar com *threads* tanto em sistemas POSIX quanto Windows. Existe ainda um [*port* da biblioteca pThreads](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/), que é POSIX, para o Windows.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Boa resposta! `+1`

Comment: Então, quer dizer que para padronizar a comunicação via socket, ou seja, que seja compilável em vários sistemas operacionais, devo usar algumas dessas bibliotecas? Se sim, tem como recomendar algumas dessas bibliotecas para trabalhar no C? Tanto para o uso de sockets e threads.

Comment: @Vynstus sim, é isto. Recomendei estas. Mas não posso dizer para você o que é melhor para sua situação. Outra possibilidade é programa para cada plataforma usando a biblioteca específica dela, em alguns casos pode ser melhor. É raro alguém adotar isto mas não deixa de ser uma possibilidade.